# Html string interpolation not seeing change from Angular's onPush strategy within observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

Using Angular 14, I have in the string template interpolation in the html. I am using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`. When the `ngOnInit()` runs and subscribe observable gets the value, I am not seeing a change in the html when `this.headerName = name;` is set. How can I fix this and still use onPush?

```html
        <div class="col-4 gx-5">
          <p>Corporate Name</p>
          <p>{{headerName}}</p>
        </div>
```

```js
  @Component({
    selector: 'app-importer-main',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  ...
     ngOnInit(): void {
      this.apiService.consumeAgenciesApi().subscribe((el) => {
        const {
          name,
        } = el[0];
  
        this.headerName = name;
```

Comment: This is a correct behavior. If you want to get displayed an up-to-date value than I'd suggest to create a BehaviorSubject or Subject and emit a new value in your subscription, or manually run `markForCheck()` or `detectChanges()` after new value is assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnPush` works great when you follow the `reactive` approach, without subscribing manually to `observables`, `pipe` the value and then use the `async` pipe like the following:

```js
name$!: Observable<string>;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.name$ = this.apiService.consumeAgenciesApi().pipe(
   map(response) => response[0]?.name
  );
}
```

```html
<!-- FYI, ng-container is not render in the DOM -->
<ng-container *ngIf="name$ | async as headerName"> 
 <div class="col-4 gx-5">
   <p>Corporate Name</p>
   <p> {{ headerName }} </p>
 </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: That extra code seems like it would make onpush less performant than the default change detection?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the detection strategy to `OnPush` means you are choosing to opt-out of the auto change detection. therefore you must manually tell angular when to update.

```
// Get the change DetectorRef so that you can trigger change detection
constructor( private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef )

// then update your subscription to trigger change detection
this.apiService.consumeAgenciesApi().subscribe({
  next: (el) => {
    const {
      name,
    } = el[0];

    this.headerName = name;
    // use either detectChanges() which forces an immediate change detection
    // or use mark for check which can be less performacne intensive. depending on your use case.
    this.cdr.markForCheck()
  }
});
```